# python wx unicode encoding

Tags: python, unicode, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a problem with wx and python which seems to be a unicode one.

I'm using Portable python 2.7.2.1 and wx-2.8-msw-unicode.

My python code at the point of failure is this statement:

```
listbox.AppendText("\n  " + dparser.parse(t['created_at']).strftime('%H-%M-%S') + "    " +t['text'] + "\n")
```

> t['text']
>
> has a value: 
>   "RT @WebbieBmx: “@AlexColebornBmx: http://t.co/cN6zSO69”watch this an #retweet"

which when printed in the DOS window from which I'm running python displays as:

> 'RT @WebbieBmx: \xe2\x80\x9c@AlexColebornBmx: http://t.co/cN6zSO69\xe2
>   \x80\x9dwatch this an #retweet'

The traceback is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "myprogs\Search_db_dev.py",
>   line 713, in onSubmit
>       self.toField.GetLineText(0))   File "F:\Portable\Portable Python 2.7.2.1\App\myprogs\process_form2_dev.py", l ine 575, in display_Tweets
>
> ```
>     listbox.AppendText("\n  " + dparser.parse(t['created_at']).strftime('%H-%M-%
> S') + "    " +t['text'] + "\n")
> ```
>
> File "F:\Portable\Portable Python
>   2.7.2.1\App\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-uni code\wx_controls.py", line 1850, in AppendText
>
> ```
>    return _controls_.TextCtrl_AppendText(*args, **kwargs)
> ```
>
> File "F:\Portable\Portable Python
>   2.7.2.1\App\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 1 5, in
>
> ```
> decode return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
> ```
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position
>   73: chara cter maps to undefined

The UnicodeDecodeError seems to occur at the end of the right double quotation mark (\xe2\x80\x9d) but I can't see why. I would be grateful for any help.

It may be a simple encoding problem, I'm afraid

Answer (score 2):

The reference to cp1252 kind of threw me when I looked at the traceback, because the text is utf8 (as one might expect when handling the text of tweets.)  The utf8 sequence on the left (\xe2\x80\x9c) doesn't seem to cause a problem, but it appears there's a space after the \xe2 in the second hex sequence, which would keep it from being decoded from utf8 properly.  When I remove that space, the decode problem goes away.  So you've got some bad utf8, which I'm not sure how you would guard against other than an explicit decode inside a try statement when you receive it from the original source.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Peter 
Many Thanks for the comment.  It seems that space got in there by mistake when I was posting, and it isn't there in my data.  So although I think I have a way forward (see abarnert response below) I would be interested to know what you were doing that made the decode problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a simple encoding problem.

The reason you don't see why is that your font isn't distinguishing between `u'”'` and `u'"'`. The former is a curly closed-quote mark, which is `'\xe2\x80\x9d'` in UTF-8. This most often happens when you edit a text file in an editor (like MS Word) that does "smart quotes".

But it's good that you found the problem now; otherwise, everything would seem to work until you gave your script to some Chinese user…

Anyway, the problem here is that you've got some code that's storing UTF-8 strings, and some other code that's trying to access them as if they were in the default encoding (your Windows OEM charset). Without seeing more of the code, it's hard to be sure what exactly you're doing wrong, but hopefully this is enough info for you to track it down.

Comment: abarnet
Many thanks for your comment. In line with what you said, when I got the UnicodeDecodeError, before using listbox.AppendText I changed the text with text.decode('utf-8').  This gave a unicode result and listbox.AppendText was happy to display this.